How to do byte[] comparison with incoming unhexed md5 string in JPA Query by using Spring boot 3 and Hiberate 6.5
I have a column varbinary(16) that stores some slug values as unhex(md5('slug')). It's mapped in entity as byte[].
private byte[] slugBinary;

And in my JPA query (using Spring boot 2.7 and Hibernate 5.6) It was working fine as
@Query("Select c From CategoryEntity c Where c.slugBinary = Unhex(Md5(:slug))") 

Where :slug is a String value.
I know Recent Versions of Hibernate 6.2.x and onward have strict comparison checking. However, I am trying to figure out how to compare the slugBinary value with the input string. Because the Above query no longer working, I am getting
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare the left expression of type 'byte[]' with the right expression of type 'java.lang.Object' 

I know the right side produces binary string and I tried this way
Where c.slugBinary = cast(Unhex(Md5(:slug)) as BINARY)

But it also not working, Any help would be appreciated.

Mysql ver 8.0.35
Spring boot 3.3
Hibernate 6.5.x
utf8mb4 unicode ci


What are the constraints?
(1) Use new version components  (Spring Boot 3 + Hibernate 6 )+ new version Database Table Schema? Q: Don’t know how to do it?
(2) Use new version components + old version Database Table Schema + Data?
Q: How to use the new version of the component to access the existing Table Data?

In addition, what is the version of the database? Different databases and different dialects may produce different Table Schema.

@life888888 please check updated question with versions and collation. Dialect is mysql8 dialect. The default one provided by spring boot. Nothing special constraints
